# Node.js app , for streaming videos ,how to captured from some other ip .?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nodejs-stream

the app will be hosted on a LAN. Whenever someone opens up the app. Two options appear on the screen. You can either set up your own stream or subscribe to someone else's stream for watching a video .

The stream is an video buffer, that is being played on either your browser or on the person's browser whose stream you are subscribing to.

For playing video, we can simply use the HTML5 player .
For subscribing to someone else's stream, i should make a textbox in which an IP address would be entered and a button to start fetching the stream.

Can someone help in help me in deciding , best approach , of doing so ?

TIA